# How to retrieve the value (string) of an array's element and use it to retrieve the property value of an entity?

Tags: symfony, twig

how to retrieve the value (string) of an array's element and retrieve the property value of an entity? I tried this:

```
{% for item in items %} //item is an entity
  {% for column in columns %} //column is just an array with name of columns
    {% set columna = column.value %}
    {{ item.columna }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: And what exactly don't work? Do you see some error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access dynamically a property of an object, you can use the [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) :

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% for column in columns %}
    {{ attribute(item , column.value) }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Thanks!!, it works, I forgot to say that `column.value` returns an error. Just `{{ attribute(item, column) }}` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for item in items %} //item is an entity
  {% for column in columns %} //column is just an array with name of columns
    {% set columna = column.value %}
    {{ attribute(item, columna) }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I recommend reading the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables).